# My build and package gives me an older version of my app

Tags: build, electron, package, electron-builder, electron-packager

i'm using Electron for the first time and have a problem.

I used a sample to make an app with Angular and Electron. When I changed a little bit i made a build to test if things are right. Since that i made a lot of new functions and updates. Now when i try to build/package my app, i got the same version i have made at the beginning and not the version i'm seeing when i made `npm-run-all -p electron:serve ng:serve` what i'm doing wrong?

I have used electron-forge, i have used electron-packager and them both got the same old version builded. And i don't know what to do now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with `extraMetadata` in your package.json :

```json
{
"build": {
    ...,
    "extraMetadata": {
      "version": "X.Y.Z"
    },
...

}
```